# Profiles in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I need help in understanding how to create profiles using the Angular framework. The idea would be, when signing in, the website changes based on the profile that’s logged in. I created a create profile component and I also created the login screen that verifies the profile that was created. But I’m having a hard time wrapping my head around how to change certain components based on the profile. Is it as simple as just creating a “logged in” component and importing it into the components that change based on the user that logged in?

Comment: Would you like to be more specific on what you need help with? Like post a piece of code and ask why it doesn't work. You need to give us more context.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a profile component, that takes as an input the user, and bind the informations to the view.
Then you can use the component inside another component that as the user isntance.

Answer (score -1):

A good way is to create a service instead of that component.

Comment: Hi Vadim and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you maybe provide an explanation of why a service would be the right approach?  Thanks!